# Image steganography based on DWT integer coefficients

Tags: image, matlab, steganography, dwt

I am trying to code DWT based steganography to hide an image inside another image. I am getting coefficients of subbands as float. How can I make them integers so that I can use lsb embedding?

Answer (score 0):

This is also known as Integer Wavelet Transform. In Matlab this is achieved using [lifting schemes](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/lwt2.html). Define a lifting scheme with `liftwave` and use `lwt2` and `ilwt2` for the transformations.

```
lshaar = liftwave('haar','int2int');

[cA cH cV cD] = lwt2(x,lshaar);            % x is your data
ilwt2(cA,cH,cV,cD,lshaar);
```